# two "that" in a row

Tags: determiners

In the Online Etymology Dictionary, the meaning of the word "contingency" is like this:

> the possibility that that which happens might not have happened

My question is that why did two "that" come in a row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first "that" introduces the *subordinate clause*, "*that which happens might not have happened*".

The second "that" is a pronoun roughly meaning "the one" or "the thing". It is modified by the *relative clause*, "which happens".

The noun phrase "*that which happens*" is the subject of "*might not have happened*".

Answer (score 0):

The word "that" can be used in many different ways.

Your example demonstrates two of them:

- In "*the possibility that …*", "that" is a conjunction of indirect statement.
  As in "*The possibility that it will happen is very small.*".
- "*that which happens*" is a noun phrase beginning with the demonstrative pronoun "that".
  As in "*Whatever it is, we'll have to live with that which happens.*".

Here's a much more complicated example with **7** "that"s in a row (plus **4 more** consecutive "that"s in that same sentence):

> Situation: you have to imagine that a teacher is explaining a text, and points to two instances of the word 'that', which each refer to another 'that' in the text.
> 'For all that' means 'Whatever you may say'.
>
> "It is true, for all <that>, [that] (that) 'that' {that} (that) 'that' refers to is not the same 'that' {that} (that) 'that' refers to."
>
> Here is each of the different 'thats' with its part of speech and an example of usage:
>
> | Word | Use | Example |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | <that> | demonstrative pronoun | Goodbye to all that |
> | [that] | conjunction of indirect statement | You know that the ice is cold. |
> | (that) | demonstrative adjective | I like that picture. |
> | 'that' | quotation of the word 'that' | He said 'that'. |
> | {that} | relative pronoun | The house that Jack built. |
>
> — wandle — [that that that that that that that | WordReference Forums](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/that-that-that-that-that-that-that.2977118/post-15055264)